# Python Runtime level error,

Tags: python, runtime-error

I'm working through a online tutorial alone and I have no idea what I'm missing.
I can't edit the code below anymore than two characters. Most of what I've tried is more than two character changes.

I need it to print `"Hello"` on one line and then on another line `"Joe"`

This is the code given;

```
print("Hello")
username = Joe 
print(username)
```

I've tried swopping the second line around. I've tried removing the second line altogether. I've tried syntax changes all to no avail.

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  In line 2 of the code you submitted:
    username = Joe 
NameError: name 'Joe' is not defined
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes around `Joe` to make it a string (similar to `"Hello"`), otherwise python will look for a variable named `Joe` and if it is not found then `NameError` will be raised:

```
username = "Joe"
```

Adding two quotes also meets your criteria of adding at most two characters.

Answer (score 0):

"Joe" is a string, so it should be `username = "Joe"`, not `username = Joe`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I had only tried to add "" with () and then was out of the character limit.